# Google_Service_Exception 403 when listing groups with PHP

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

Getting an error when trying to list the groups of my domain through the PHP Directory API. The really weird thing is that if I list the groups using [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), it works seamlessly with these scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member

**Note:** I'm not using a service account do this. My email address has super admin access, so I'm assuming this should be fine when trying to manage groups and group members? I'm using Slim 3 to handle the applications details. My client is initialized and authenticated (according to a quick `var_dump` on the object), yet I get an error when trying to do:

```
 $service = new \Google_Service_Directory($this->client);
 var_dump($service->groups->listGroups(["domain" => "example.google.com"])); // placeholder domain for SO
```

and here is the error I'm receiving when trying to load the page so I can list the groups:

```
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php(240): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Directory.php(2122): Google_Service_Resource->call('list', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/aslists/src/controllers/DashboardController.php(23): Google_Service_Directory_Groups_Resource->listGroups(Array)
#8 [internal function]: a_s\controllers\DashboardController->index(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
...
#18 {main}
```

Why would the query fail using the PHP API, but succeed on OAuth playground?

#### Update 1

My apologies in advance, this will contain a lot of code...

I spent some time tinkering around following the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/php#step_4_run_the_sample) example where my `client_secret.json` file is loaded into the application like so:

```
$this->client->setAuthConfigFile('/path/to/client_secret.json');
$credentialsPath = $this->expandHomeDirectory('/path/to/.credentials/admin-directory_v1-php-quickstart.json');

if(file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
    $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
}

if(isset($accessToken)) {
    $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}

if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $this->client->refreshToken($this->client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $this->client->getAccessToken());
}

$this->service = new \Google_Service_Directory($this->client);
```

If I use this method, it works perfectly with my application – very strange. I did additional investigation between this method and using Google to sign into the application and I was unable to find anything conclusive. Given that, it *should* work if I use Google to sign in, but it still doesn't.

Here is how I am initializing the client:

```
class GoogleController extends Controller {

    private static $APP_NAME = "Lists Manager";
    private static $CLIENT_ID = "...";
    private static $CLIENT_SECRET = "...";
    private static $REDIRECT_URI = "postmessage";
    private static $ACCESS_TYPE = "offline";
    private static $scopes = [
        \Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE,
        \Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,
        \Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP,
        \Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER,
        \Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER
    ];

    protected $client;

    public function __construct($container) {
        parent::__construct($container);

        $this->client = new \Google_Client();
        $this->client->setApplicationName(self::$APP_NAME);
        $this->client->setClientId(self::$CLIENT_ID);
        $this->client->setClientSecret(self::$CLIENT_SECRET);
        $this->client->setRedirectUri(self::$REDIRECT_URI);
        $this->client->setScopes(self::$scopes);
        $this->client->setAccessType(self::$ACCESS_TYPE);
    }

}
```

From here, I have another controller which extends `GoogleController` that contains an ajax endpoint (i.e. where the access code it POSTed to). The code for this is shown below:

```
class LoginController extends GoogleController {

    public function __construct($container) {
        parent::__construct($container);
    }

    public function login($request, $response) {
        if($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            unset($_SESSION[GoogleController::AS_PERSISTENT_CLIENT_OBJECT]);

            $this->tokens = $this->client->authenticate($request->getBody()->getContents());
            // $this->client->setAccessToken($this->token); // Not sure if I need to do this. Either way, I still get the exception
        }

        $_SESSION[GoogleController::AS_PERSISTENT_CLIENT_OBJECT] = serialize($this->client);

        return $response->withStatus(200)
                        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                        ->write($this->generateJsonSuccess('dashboard'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your code for authentication? There may be something wrong with the authorization implementation, let start investigating there because you received a `403:Not Authorized to access` error.

Comment: Updated with the requested code!